# Adding a class to navbar when scrolling (transp. background) makes text also transp

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a bigger private project, and stumbled upon some problems. As this is my first post, I have to add: yes I made some research, and I'm very sorry if this topic is already covered, feel free to state that if that's the case and I will remove the post - but all the help is welcome!

So, much ado about nothing so far - here we go:

I'm trying to get a custom navigation bar to change its color from completely transparent to white; opacity: 0.5; - this is of course pretty easy, but I also want to change the "navbar"'s font color to black, which in the beginning is white. I have tried to do this some ways, but can't figure out how to do (the navbar just turns completely white; opacity: 0.5; when jQuery function runs). I have some thoughts about why this is happening, but nothing seems to work for me. I'll add the codes, and maybe some nice soul knows the answer.

### CSS

```
.navbar {
    padding-bottom: 8%; 
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navbarscrolled {
    background-color: white; 
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: -1;
}

.navbar .a1 {
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: RALEWAY; 
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar .a12 {
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: RALEWAY; font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar .a2 {
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    margin-left: 30%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: RALEWAY; font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar .a3 {
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    margin-left: 60%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: RALEWAY;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar .a4 {
    margin-top: 2.5%;;
    margin-left: 70%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: RALEWAY; 
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

### JS

```
var header = $(".navbar");
var headerScroll = "navbarscrolled";

$(document).scroll( function() {
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 0) {

        header.addClass(headerScroll);

    }
    else {

        header.removeClass(headerScroll);

    }
});
```

(as you see I want the .a1-4 to change from white to black, thanks)

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you show the exact problem with a working snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `opacity` is apllied to `header` and all elements inside it.
One solution is to use [rbga](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#rgb-color) as given here.

```
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NsFSL/2/

Comment: This didn't work for me, but the rest of my code was very messy and I think something wrote over the earlier part. When digging into your answer this would be a possible solution! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new CSS rule targeting the the font using the class that your jQuery added. It should overwrite your current CSS rule. Something like this:

```
.navbar .a1 { /*Your current css rule */ 
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: RALEWAY; 
    font-weight: 600;
}
.navbar.navbarscrolled .a1 { /*Css rule when class is added */ 
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: I tried that as a first idea, but didn't work! All my code was very messy and rewrote everything, and it works better now with your answer. Thanks! - or something haha..